# iOS - weird UIView Offset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I use this function to create image from [uiview](/questions/tagged/uiview):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, 0.0f);
[view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage * snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return snapshotImage;
```

The code `UIImage * snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();` make my screen have a glitch:
[image]

How can I resolve this issue? This only happen in [ios8](/questions/tagged/ios8). I do not have this issue in [ios7](/questions/tagged/ios7).

Comment: Where are you calling this code from? In iOS8 UIScreen bounds now reflect the interface orientation and not the device, so it could be view.bounds is returning different values at the point you are calling the code?

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel How to check interface orientation against device orientation? I just check my `view.bounds.size` and it appear to be the right `uiview` size and orientation.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel I think you are right about the conflict of the orientation. I just check the offset width which match exactly the height of the screen.

Comment: `self.interfaceOrientation` will tell you the interface orientation. This is deprecated now, but works pre iOS8. For the device orientation use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]`

Answer (score 0):

After much of trial and error, I found the course:

```
[view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
```

when `afterScreenUpdates:` set to `YES`, I will have that glitch. Once I set it to `NO`, the problem go away.